# Number chapter disappeared

Tags: numbering, chapters

I have no idea what happend. I had to reset TexStudio because it didn't show me the preview. Now there isn't chapter's numbers.
Before I had: Chapter 1, Chapter 2 etc. with its title. Now there's only the title without "Chapter 1", ...
Sections starts from 0 and go on to the end of the document. Before the section in Chapter 1 was 1.1, 1.2 etc. Now 0.1, 0.2 0.100

This is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,italian,oneside,openright,12pt,draft]{book}
\usepackage{cmap} % makes PDF searchable
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Latin Modern font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % needed for fontenc
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,final]{easyoutput}
\makeindex
\usepackage[binding=0.8cm]{layaureo}  % migliore copertura foglio A4 + margine rilegatura
\usepackage{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}[2004/07/16] % didascalie figure
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
% tabelle
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \frenchspacing
    \frontmatter

\tableofcontents
%\listoffigures


\input{introduzione}


\input{capitolo1}
\input{capitolo2}
\input{capitolo3}

\backmatter

\medskip

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliografia}


\end{document}
```

In capitolo1 (=Chapter 1) I start the file with `\chapter{}`
It's not caused by `\chapter*{}`. Before the reset everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\frontmatter` removes the `\chapter` numbering, so you'll have to use `\mainmatter` somewhere... either in `introduzione.tex` or `capitolo1.tex`. However, I'd place it inside your main TeX file since it aids in the visible document structure.

---

`\frontmatter` is defined like this inside [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co):

```
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
```

It sets the `\if@mainmatter` switch to `false`, which is used inside `\@chapter` to set a numbered chapter:

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```